# SwiftUI: confirmationDialog disappearing after one second

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Please help me get rid of this problem:

Steps to reproduce my problem:

1. Tap "Edit My Name" Button
2. Inside .sheet, tap on the TextField and then with keyboard still shown, scroll all the way down
3. Tap on the Button "Delete Name"
4. **Here is the problem**:

   **confirmationDialog appears only for one second, and then
   disappears, not giving the user any chance (or less than one second chance)
   to tap one of the confirmationDialog's Buttons!**

Here's my code:

ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var myName = "Joe"
    @State private var isEditingName = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("My name is: \(myName)")
        Button("Edit My Name") {
            isEditingName = true
        }
        .padding()
        .sheet(isPresented: $isEditingName) {
            EditView(name: $myName)
        }
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

EditView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct EditView: View {
    @Binding var name: String
    @State private var isShowingConfirmationDialog = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                TextField("Name", text: $name)
            }
            Section {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(0..<50, id: \.self) { number in
                        Text("\(number)")
                    }
                }
            }
            Section {
                deleteNameWithConfirmationDialog
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var deleteNameWithConfirmationDialog: some View {
        Button("Delete Name", role: .destructive) {
            isShowingConfirmationDialog = true
        }
        .confirmationDialog("Are you sure you want to delete name?", isPresented: $isShowingConfirmationDialog) {
            Button("Delete Name", role: .destructive) {
                name = ""
            }
            Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) { }
        } message: {
            Text("Are you sure you want to delte name?")
        }
    }
    
}

struct EditView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        EditView(name: .constant(String("Joe")))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you move the `.confirmationDialogue` out of the `Form`:

```
struct EditView: View {
    @Binding var name: String
    @State private var isShowingConfirmationDialog = false
    
    var body: some View {

        Form {
            Section {
                TextField("Name", text: $name)
            }
            Section {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(0..<50, id: \.self) { number in
                        Text("\(number)")
                    }
                }
            }
            Section {
                Button("Delete Name", role: .destructive) {
                    isShowingConfirmationDialog = true
                }
            }
        }
        
        .confirmationDialog("Are you sure you want to delete name?", isPresented: $isShowingConfirmationDialog) {
            Button("Delete Name", role: .destructive) {
                name = ""
            }
            Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) { }
        } message: {
            Text("Are you sure you want to delete name?")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep `.confirmationDialog` inside of the `Form`, or if you are using `.confirmationDialog` to manage deleting items within a `List`, you can also avoid the immediate dismissal by excluding the `.destructive` role from the deleteButton in `.swipeActions`.

```
var body: some View {
    List { // this could also be a Form
        ForEach(listItems) { item in 
            ItemRow(item: item) // confirmationDialog is in ItemRow
        }.swipeActions { 
            Button(action: { /* deleteMethodHere */ }) { 
                Image(systemName: "trash") 
            }.tint(.red) // to keep the swipe button red
        }
    }
}
```